# Get C# DateTime Ticks from html <Input> of type DateTime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I was hoping one of you guys might be able to help me. I am a bit stuck and I am very new to javascript.

I need to post a DateTime value (as c# ticks) to a webservice call from a mobile application. The mobile application is written in html/javascript.

Currently I have code that works for a normal Date. It is as follows.

```
function getTicksFromDatePicker(value) {
    var dateparts = value.split("-");
    //date format(Fullyear,month,date) 
    var startDate = new Date(dateparts[0], (dateparts[1] - 1).toString(), 
              (dateparts[2]).toString()); 
    var ret = ((startDate.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000);
    if (isNaN(ret)) {
        ret = 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This code works perfectly if I use a normal html < input type="date" > and pass its value to my function.

I need to write a function which takes the value from an input of type="datetime" and convert it into c# ticks. I am having trouble doing so. I googled around but I did not find anything on how to. I would greatly appreciate any help you guys can provide me with.

Comment: use `Date.parse` to convert your date string to a `Date`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Does Date.Parse() include the Time as well ? also, is it the same as c# ticks ?

Comment: Ok. So with some research. Date.parse() returns an epoch time, which is not the same as c# ticks. but can be easily converted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So my new solution is as follows. If anyone can provide a better solution, I will be willing to accept it. :)

```
function toCsharpticks(value)
{
   var dateRet = Date.parse(value);
   dateRet = (dateRet * 10000) + 621355968000000000
   return dateRet
}
```

There are 621355968000000000 epoch ticks for javascript from Ist Jan 1900 to Ist Jan 1970. And here 10000 are the ticks per milliseconds.

If anyone has a more elegant solution. I am more than happy to accept it instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var startDate = new Date(dateparts[0], (dateparts[1] - 1).toString(), 
              (dateparts[2]).toString());
```

This above statement returns only the **`date`** and where the time 00:00:00

So what you have to  do is to add time to `startDate`.